# How to check if a String contains multiple values and ignore case with StringUtils

Tags: string, scala

I wrote a method to check if a string contains various values.

```
  def validateString(metricValue: String): Boolean = {
    (!StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(metricValue, "metric_1")
      && StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(metricValue, "metric_2")
      || StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(metricValue, "metric_3")
  }
```

Then I decided to reduce the last two checks to a single one but haven't found anything that may be helpful in `commons-lang-2.6`. 
I know there is a similar method in `lang 3`: `StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(str, "val1", "val2", "val3"))`. But I need something like `containsAnyIgnoreCase`.

Is there a way to check if any of multiple values is present in a String ignoring the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `StringUtils`:

```
def validateString(metricValue: String): Boolean =
  List("metric_2", "metric_3").exists(metricToCheck => StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(metricValue, metricToCheck))
```

Comment: Am I correct that it will return true if the `metricValue` String contains both `"metric_2" AND "metric_3"`? I need it to return true if the string contains `"metric_2" OR "metric_3"`

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
List("metric_2", "metric_3")
  .map(_.toLowerCase)
  .contains(metricValue.toLowerCase)
```